# What are the pros/cons for using ZeroMQ Binary Star vs Zookeeper for High Availability?

Tags: scalability, zeromq, high-availability, apache-zookeeper

[High Availability Pair-Binary-Star-Pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#High-Availability-Pair-Binary-Star-Pattern)

Looking to add high availability master/master capabilities in my system, currently considering ZeroMQ Binary Star vs ZooKeeper.

Comment: You should be more specific about what the problem you are trying to solve is.

Answer (score 5):

The BStar pattern is just one of infinitely many possible patterns not "the" 0MQ pattern. You could quite likely use Tom Cocagne's Paxos implementation which runs over 0MQ: https://github.com/cocagne/zpax and https://github.com/cocagne/paxos.

Answer (score 4):

ZMQ treatment of the split-brain problem (two servers thinking they are the master when one does not see the other) is limited and requires a shared network connection (even per the link you provided) where as good as ZooKeepr's is top-notch (You can see t[his Stackoverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106984/avoiding-split-brain-votes-and-quorum) for discussion on splitbrain). Also ZooKeeper is [adopted by a lot of major products](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/PoweredBy) like Hadoop, HBase, Solr etc.(l