# OK to put zookeeper ensemble on same machines as the processes they serve?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Is it OK or would it lead to problems wrt split/brain etc?

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry about split brain. ZK only works when it has quorum majority. If nodes do not have quorum majority they reject writes. This ensures Zk will not work in split-brain states. A good explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106984/avoiding-split-brain-votes-and-quorum).

You should not put the client on the same machine client can influence the ZK's performance (the client is a memory hog, consumes excessive network, etc.).

Comment: I'm not too worried about ZK performance. Apart from leader election -  and leader changes should happen rarely in practice - I intend to use it as a name service and maybe for do-once-at-startup things like getting configuration.